# Compare two list with order using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

If list 1 has the following properties: `{A,B,C}` and list 2 has the following properties {A,C,B}, comparing them should give the result "not matched".

The item order also needs to be same.

Comment: Please define what your problem is.

Comment: we need more context about what it is that youre asking and trying to achieve. Also an example of your code wont hurt

Comment: Verify my answer if that works then accept or I will delete, Its no fun to have pointless down voters down-voting the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

Not pretending to get this as the answer but for future people who get here, [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) should work:

```
enumerable1.SequenceEqual(enumerable2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do this in Linq...

Try something like this

```
public bool CompareOrderedLists<T>(List<T> one, List<T> theOther)
{
    if(one.Length != theOther.Length) return false;

    for(var i = 0; i < one.Length; i++)
    {
        if(one[i] != theOther[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Actually you can do pretty much everything with data through LINQ. Just add more specific extensions.

Comment: Your solution will be correct if you `Order / Sort` both the collections, else the issue mentioned by OP will come in the picture, where two collections don't have same order and hence they would be unequal, which is not correct

Comment: I believe his question says the exact opposite of that.  He is saying they shouldn't match if they are in different orders. @MrinalKamboj

Comment: @meganaut, genuinely not sure, but in my view that would hardly be an issue, challenge is always to compare elements in different list in any order. I think OP may care to define, nonetheless +1 for your effort and view.

Answer (score 0):

> What you want ?

Compare two lists, with any order of elements.

Following is the Generic code:

```
internal class GenericListComparer<T>
{
    internal static bool Compare(List<T> firstCollection, List<T> secondCollection)
    {
        return firstCollection.TrueForAll(secondCollection.Contains) &&
               secondCollection.TrueForAll(firstCollection.Contains);
    }
}
```

> Usage:

```
List<int> aList = new List<int> { 1,2,3,4};

List<int> bList = new List<int> { 1,4,3,2};

bool result  = GenericListComparer<int>.Compare(aList,bList); // Matched

bList = new List<int> { 1,4,3,2,5};

result  = GenericListComparer<int>.Compare(aList,bList); // Un-Matched
```

> Time Complexity - O(n)

Comment: Will work for all the types with `default Comparer`, in case type is complex, then would need explicit `IEqualityComparer`

Comment: I think they down-vote because you are feeding the OP straight answer without showing some efforts.